# Finding min and max and other functions, pandas series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Let `ss` be a pandas series of floats.

Let `x` be a float.

`x+1` and `ss+1` work as expected.

`x/5` and `ss/5` work as expected.

However `min(x,5)` works, but in order to get the same behavior with the series I must do `ss.apply(lambda y: min(y,6))` and this is a pain for the following reason:

What if I want to do a batch of calculations on a series, and then as new elements appear, I want to do on the fly calculations?

In other words I'd like a function `f` so that I can apply `f` to a series (or multiple series) as well as applying `f` to a float (or multiple floats), and ideally apply `f` to a combination of floats and series.

I care about this because there may be many such transformations and I would highly prefer not maintaining two different versions of each transformation, one for batches and one for instant one-offs.

Comment: Try numpy's min function (you might need to feed the args as a list.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a scalar, you can either convert it to a Series and work on the Series

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(range(10, 20))
print s.min()
f = 6
print s.append(pd.Series([f])).min()
```

or convert the Series to a scalar value and use the normal `min()` function

```
print min(s.min(), f)
```

Comment: Looks like it could work as a one-off, though not very elegant.  What did you think of @Paul H's suggestion above.